# How to print a variable which contains '$' in it in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash script which contains a variable called "line", and I want to print it's content.
The problem is that the "line" variable is a string which contains the '$' char.

My question is how can I print the value of the "line" variable, without replacing the dollars with variables.

For example, if "line" is containing "a$#gz%^", this code:

```
 echo $line
```

Will output this:

> a0gz%^

And if I'll put the '$line' in single quotes, it will just print '$line':

```
 echo '$line'
```

> $line

Hope you'll be able to help.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. `line='a$#gz%^'; echo $line` in bash prints `a$#gz%^`. The problem is likely that `line` actually contains `a0gz%^`, and that expansion of `$#` occurred when you set the `line` variable.

Comment: Q: How do I assign a value that has "$" to a bash variable?  A: Easy: use single quotes: `line='a$#gz%'`.  Q: How do I print that variable?  A: Easy: just `echo $line`.

Comment: ^^ I would recommend `echo "$line"`...

Answer (score 1):

You have to quote the string when you assign it to the variable:

```
line='a$#gz%^'
```

Otherwise, `$#` is expanded before the assignment.

To output the literal variable, use double quotes

```
echo "$line"
```

---

It looks confusing at first, but it is actually pretty simple (at least to a first approximation):

- `string with $line in it` -- never what you want, particularly if it includes a variable. OK if there is no variable and the string is just letters and numbers (and pattern characters if you want them to be expanded). Expands variables, splits into words, expands filename patterns.
- `"string with $line in it"` -- expands variables, but doesn't word split or expand filename patterns
- `'string with $line in it'` -- literal string, just the characters between the apostrophes

Comment: The problem is that the line variable is assigned with a loop over file lines:

while read line;do

...

done < $fileName

Comment: @OrNevo: The `$#` in the variable will not be expanded by any form of variable insertion. If you have a clearer example, *edit your question*. Do not put important information in comments.

Comment: @ornevo: that `while read` loop will *not* trigger what you claim to see -- *unless* the input is coming from a here-doc. In that case, the `$#` will be expanded in the here-doc unless you quote the end marker (`<<'END'`)

Answer (score 0):

> You can store string in variable having special characters by giving escape sequence like below -

```
line="a\$#gz%^"
```

And then `echo $line`